# What is the difference between Child and Element of a container?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

What is the difference between Child and Element of a container?
Why do the containers like Spark VGroup have different sets of methods for both Child and Elements?

Can anyone explain me the difference in the simplest way?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hey please see my answer and please accept it if answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `addChild` method is used for adding a `DisplayObject`, which is a method from pure actionscript. So you would typically add Sprite, MovieClips etc. Widely used in action script based projects

The Flex classes like VGroup are written on top of the base actionscript classes, and therefore have an extra `addElement` method to be able to add an `IVisualElement`, which can also be an FXG for example, or other Flex based components such as `UIComponent`, `Group` etc.

However, I doubt that calling `addChild` on a `VGroup` will actually provide desired results and may result in errors.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The type [`IVisualElement`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IVisualElement.html) and with it all the `*Element` methods from [`IVisualElementContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IVisualElementContainer.html) were introduced in Flex SDK 4.0 as part of the spark layout and lifecycle features.

You are still free to build your own components based on UIComponents without having the spark features and only with the `*Child` methods.

All classes that extend [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29) of course inherit the `*Child` methods but in classes like [`Group`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=blob;f=frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/Group.as;h=6b490a393438fc7b143fcb51ae238299847d8020;hb=HEAD#l2194) (and [`SkinnableComponent`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=blob;f=frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.as;h=2a8c73002b2e56adf99ec3449caa491dec405c6e;hb=HEAD#l1135)) those methods have been overwritten to throw an error, as one needs to use the `*Element` methods to use the Spark features.

As Flex 4 supports using the MX layout as well as the Spark layout (there are options to use only one of them or both side by side when compiling) those methods could not be marked as deprecated in `Group` and `SkinnableComponent`, wich would at least trigger a compiler warning instead of a runtime error.